# Unable to install Deno in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, deno

I am trying to install Deno in my Ubuntu machine but I can't. Ubuntu Version is 18.04.

I am using this command:

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
```

It has provided by Deno's official page. After installing Deno, I set below configuration in `.bash_profile`.

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/home/azmul/.local"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

After doing this when I try to run **deno** command on my terminal. I always found **'deno' not found**  on my terminal. I don't know what should i do. If anyone has a good sound about this please give me an answer.

Comment: Have you sourced your `.bash_profile` afterwards?

Comment: You need to set `DENO_INSTALL` before installation if you want to use a non-default location during install. See: https://github.com/denoland/deno_install#environment-variables

Answer (score 6):

Try running this:

```sh
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sudo DENO_INSTALL=/usr/local sh
```

`DENO_INSTALL` - The directory in which to install Deno. This defaults to `$HOME/.deno`. The executable is placed in `$DENO_INSTALL/bin`.

In this case, you should get :

> Deno was installed successfully to /usr/local/bin/deno

Comment: It's really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Edit `~/.bashrc` file

Do the following changes

`gedit ~/.bashrc`

Add the following code to end of the line

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.deno/bin:$PATH"`

source `.bashrc` file

`source ~/.bashrc`

Now check

`deno -V`

It will show the version of deno like

> deno 1.0.3

Comment: this worked, but i had to check with `deno -version`

Answer (score 2):

I've not had any issues installing on 18.04. The `deno` executable
should have installed to `~/.local/bin`:

```
$ ls -l ~/.local/bin
total 60944
-rwxr-xr-x 1 srackham srackham 62400040 Feb 12 19:10 deno

$ which deno
/home/srackham/.local/bin/deno
``
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up your `.bashrc` file.

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Then, edit the `.bashrc` file and add the following commands.

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/home/azmul/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Finally, source `.bashrc` file in shorter form.

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by editing `~/.bashrc` file.

Do following-

1. `vi ~/.bashrc`
2. Add this command at the bottom (replace {username} with your
   username)- `export PATH="/home/{username}/.deno/bin:$PATH"`
3. `source ~/.bashrc`

**NOTE** : For me, deno installed at `/home/{username}/.deno/bin` and NOT at `~/.local/bin`

Answer (score -1):

Moving the 'deno' file is worked for me.

First, I navigate to ~/.deno/bin/
and then,

```
sudo mv deno /usr/local/bin/
```

That's it.