# Bun Not Found After Running Installation Script

Tags: bun

I have ran the installation script by pasting this code:

```
$ curl https://bun.sh/install | bash
```

However, when I try to get the version of bun, it says it could not find it:

```
$ bun --version

Command 'bun' not found, did you mean:

  command 'ben' from deb ben (0.9.0ubuntu2)
  command 'bus' from deb atm-tools (1:2.5.1-4)
  command 'zun' from deb python3-zunclient (4.0.0-0ubuntu1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with bun.

Comment: This is a Bun installation script and we have answered this question 3 times in the Bun discord.  People are assuming that the installation script would add Bun to path similar to what Deno does.  This will help stop us from feeling like broken record players and waste time @KevinB

Comment: You can also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60217812/10873797 for precedence

Comment: @sno2 not everyone is on discord. When the main install page doesn't explain such a vital step you can expect questions. At least the instructions are in the terminal now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue running on Windows 10 WSL2 Ubuntu-22.04 with Bun v0.1.5.

The solution (and more detail just in case anyone needs it) below:

The executable for bun is in the directory "/home/username/.bun". You need to add this to your $PATH so that this can be found when typing bun commands such as "bun --help".

The bun setup process does not add this path so you need to do it yourself.

Two ways to do this :

#### (1) Manual method

Type in the terminal:

```
export BUN_INSTALL="/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.bun"
export PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Replacing YOUR_USERNAME with your real username (the current username can be found by typing 'whoami' in the terminal).

Note: This process will have to be REPEATED for every new shell you open.

#### (2) Automatic method

Edit the .bashrc file :

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

at the end of this file add

```
BUN_INSTALL="/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.bun"
PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Replacing YOUR_USERNAME with your real username (the current username can be found by typing 'whoami' in the terminal).

(Remember to save your changes with Ctrl-O)

Note: You will NEED TO OPEN A NEW SHELL for this to work OR type 'source ~/.bashrc' to use in the current terminal.

You should now be able to run bun commands in any new shell.

Comment: Your username should be lowercase() even it's capital letters `export BUN_INSTALL="/home/administrator/.bun"
export PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: The install script says `Added "~/.bun/bin" to $PATH in "~/.bashrc"` though. So, should it not have been added automatically?

Answer (score 6):

According to the source code [install.sh#L115](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/blob/702749319636faf2a96f79d201ed0a7a25af06dd/src/cli/install.sh#L115-L120), it will install to `$HOME/.bun/bin` by default.

You can change the `BUN_INSTALL` env to change the installation dir. However, if you prefer to keep it simple, here is how I do it (*use `sudo ln` if necessary*):

```bash
curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash && \
  ln -s $HOME/.bun/bin/bun /usr/local/bin/bun
```

`bun` is now available globally.

You can use this approach in the `Dockerfile` as it will make your Dockerfile cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! It works great in ubuntu docker but not alpine. How can I make it work in alpine?

Answer (score 5):

```
export BUN_INSTALL="/Users/manendra/.bun"
export PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

add these to your .bashrc, .zshrc or you can use export command to use for current session.

Note: Change your username place of (manendra) "/Users/manendra/.bun"

Answer (score 4):

If you have Node installed you can use

```
npm install -g bun
```

Answer (score 2):

The installation script says a message at the end telling you how to add bun to your PATH manually.  Here is that output:

```
Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.bashrc (or similar)

   BUN_INSTALL="/home/sno2/.bun"
   PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

I advise you re-run the installation command and copy the environment variables and add them to your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, for me installing bun with NPM worked.

```
npm i -g bun
```

Answer (score 2):

For install [bun](https://bun.sh/), after you i ran `curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash` command, terminal says:

```
bun was installed successfully to ~/.bun/bin/bun 
Added "~/.bun/bin" to $PATH in "~/.bashrc"
```

Then i ask to ChatGPT and try then its worked.

First run this command

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following section to the end of the file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.bun/bin"
```

Save and close then run this command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Run this,

```
bun
```

Boom worked!

```
Bun: a fast JavaScript runtime, package manager, bundler and test runner. (1.0.0)
```

Comment: works on Ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 1):

Manually add the directory to ~/.bashrc (or similar):

```
 export BUN_INSTALL="$HOME/.bun" 
 export PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for Dockerfile

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
RUN echo 'export BUN_INSTALL="$HOME/.bun"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The command export `PATH=$PATH/root/.bun/bin/bun` adds `/root/.bun/bin/bun` to the PATH environment variable.

The $PATH variable in the command represents the current value of the PATH environment variable. By appending `/root/.bun/bin/bun` to $PATH, you are adding this directory to the list of directories that the shell searches when you type a command.
tory.

Note that this command assumes that the bun executable file is located in the `/root/.bun/bin` directory. If it is located in a different directory, you should modify the command accordingly.

If you have problem running bun in scripts. Check here.

```
/root/.bun/bin/bun
```

copy bun from there to this path. Or the path bun.service first check where bun is:

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

give permission to bun where it's first checked by the scripts. Be careful! Not the linux shell, but inside of scripts.

```
sudo chmod +x bun
```

to make ubuntu sudo environment variables available:

To make `sudo bun` available in Ubuntu, follow these steps:

1. Open a terminal on your Ubuntu system.
2. Use the `sudo visudo` command to edit the sudoers file:

```bash
sudo visudo
```

3. Find the line that sets the `secure_path`. It will look something like this:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

4. Add the path to the `bun` executable (which is `$HOME/.bun/bin`) to the `secure_path`. You can use the `$(echo $HOME)` command to get your home directory dynamically:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:$(echo $HOME)/.bun/bin"
```

5. Save and exit the editor. In `visudo`, this is typically done by pressing `Esc` followed by `:wq` and pressing Enter.
6. After saving the changes to the sudoers file, the `sudo bun` command should now be available.

Remember to be careful while editing the sudoers file, as any syntax errors can cause problems with your system. Always use `visudo` to edit the sudoers file to prevent such issues.

Comment: Beware that however it can not find the .env variable. it's undefined. You need to go that location and run or make `sudo bun` available

Comment: Ok, this is frustrating. You can't reach .env variables outside of its own directory

`cd /usr/local/lsws/nodes/bun; bun /usr/local/lsws/nodes/bun/index.ts`

Make this. Final solution right now. Or 

`cd /root/.bun/bin/bun /usr/local/lsws/nodes/bun; bun /usr/local/lsws/nodes/bun/index.ts`

`/usr/local/lsws/nodes/bun` is where you script located as directory

Answer (score 0):

update your mac Os, your mac Os should be at least version 12 or at least that was my case

Answer (score -2):

From the installer, last message is:

To get started, run

exec /bin/zsh
bun --help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).